# Generalised Confirmation Box in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

In one of my Interview I have been asked a Question.

You have a asp.net Application with 5 to 6 pages, Every page contains at least two button controls(i.e Submit and Cancel button). You need to add the confirmation on all the button in an application.

The process  Should be designed in such a way that we do not have to call the code on all button click(either client or server side)

So please do the needful, How can I achieve the same.

Comment: That is a very vague question. I guess you can bind the logic using jQuery on load of every page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Multiple Events to a Single Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ycbsc785%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Create an Event as below.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button) sender;
    Label1.Text = b.ID;
}
```

and set it on all `button_click` handlers

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" onclick="Button_Click" runat="server" 
  Text="Save" /> 
<br />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" onclick="Button_Click" runat="server"
  Text="Cancel" />
```

In the event handler, declare a variable whose type matches the controls that raise the event.Assign the first argument of the event handler to the variable, casting it to the appropriate type.